# Libgdx draw and pack sprites are black on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, game-development

I'm rendering sprites (game cards with one image and a table) on Android for a game and pack them with a PixmapPacker afterwards. When I am running the code with the Android emulator, the sprites are drawn well on the png file of the atlas, but the background of the file is completely black with some glitchy yellow pixels on the side of the sprites. Running the same code on my phone results in an almost completely black png with all my sprites black (only my "back.png" is drawn).

Have I cleared all buffers correctly or am I doing something wrong with the order of `m_fbo.begin()` and `m_fbo.end()`? Also I am not sure if it is necessary to call `spriteBatch.begin()` and `spriteBatch.end()` everytime inside the loop.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Sprite sprite;
BitmapFont font;

Texture texture;
OrthographicCamera cam;
FrameBuffer m_fbo = null;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Pixmap pixmap;
Skin skin;

public AtlasGenerator() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
    cam.position.set(new Vector2(w / 2, h / 2), 1);
    cam.update();

    PixmapPacker packer = new PixmapPacker(packer_width, packer_height, Pixmap.Format.RGB565, padding, true);
    //packer.setTransparentColor(Color.BLACK); // Is this necessary?
    font = new BitmapFont();
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    cam.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    Table table = new Table(skin);
    m_fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGB565, w, h, false);
    m_fbo.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    //Gdx.gl.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);

    int cardsCounter = game.getCounter();
    for (int cardID = 0; cardID < cardsCounter; cardID++) {
        System.out.println("Generating card " + (cardID + 1) + " of " + cardsCounter);

        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(game.get(cardID).getImages().get(0).getFilename()));
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);

        /* adding data to table here...*/

        /* Rendering */
        spriteBatch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1, 1, 1f);

        spriteBatch.draw(sprite, 0, h - newh, neww, newh);
        table.draw(spriteBatch, 1f);
        spriteBatch.end();

        ByteBuffer buf;
        pixmap = new Pixmap(w, h, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
        buf = pixmap.getPixels();
        Gdx.gl.glReadPixels(1, 1, w, h, GL20.GL_RGB, GL20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        pixmap = flipPixmap(pixmap);

        // convert pixmap to RGB565
        Pixmap.Format format = Pixmap.Format.RGB565; //desired format
        if (pixmap.getFormat()!=format) { //perform conversion if necessary
            Pixmap tmp = new Pixmap(pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight(), format);
            tmp.drawPixmap(pixmap, 0, 0); //copy pix to tmp
            pixmap.dispose(); //dispose old pix
            pixmap = tmp; //swap values
        }

        //packer.updatePageTextures();
        //packer.updateTextureAtlas();
        //packer.updateTextureRegions();

        packer.pack(String.valueOf(cardID), pixmap);
    }
    m_fbo.end();

    System.out.println("Finished generating cards");
    System.out.println("Start generating card pack...");

    PixmapPackerIO.SaveParameters saveParameters = new PixmapPackerIO.SaveParameters();
    saveParameters.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest;
    saveParameters.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Nearest;
    packer.pack("back", new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("back.png")));
    PixmapPackerIO pixmapPackerIO = new PixmapPackerIO();
    try {
        pixmapPackerIO.save(Gdx.files.external("cards.atlas"), packer, saveParameters);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Finished generating card pack");
    packer.dispose();
    dispose();
}
```

Comment: One thing you can try is changing Pixmap.Format. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html#FrameBuffer-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format-int-int-boolean-boolean- says that only 3 of them are "color renderable". That's just a guess, I don't think I can help you any more than that since I don't deal with half the classes you are using.

Comment: I added a conversion for my pixmap to RGB.565 but the result didn't change. Thanks anyways.

Comment: It might have something to do with `Gdx.gl.glReadPixels()` as mentioned in this post: https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20779 But I don't get the hang of how to solve this in combination with my own `FrameBuffer` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by removing the OpenGL code and working with a TextureRegion:

```
        m_fboRegion = new TextureRegion(m_fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
        m_fboRegion.flip(false, true);
        m_fbo.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        /* adding some data to sprite and table */

        spriteBatch.begin();
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1, 1, 1f);
        spriteBatch.draw(sprite, 0, h - newh, neww, newh);
        table.draw(spriteBatch, 1f);
        spriteBatch.end();

        pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, w, h);
        pixmap = flipPixmap(pixmap);

        m_fbo.end();
```